# Can not convert Future data to exact data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Future to return some information from Firebase database that return Future .Now i wanted to convert bool.Here i am faceting null .But into the then function i found my value but when i return it its remain null.

```
 Future<bool> _isfav(String post_key)  async {
 bool _is_fav;

await   FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child(Common.user)
    .child(Common.number)
    .child("favourite")
    .child(post_key)
    .once()
    .then((v) {
  print(v.value);
  if (v.value != null) {
    _is_fav = true;
  } else {
     _is_fav= false;
  }
}).catchError((err) => print(err));
 return _is_fav;  }
```

This code perfectly fine .But now

```
  bool read_fav(String index)  {

bool data;

_isfav(index).then((v){


    data= v;

    print(data); /// printing data


});

print(data); //printing null
return  data; //returning null   }
```

When i print data into the then function its show my data but when i return  it its return null.

i wanted calling the function from here

```
 child: Icon(
                                Icons.favorite,
                                color:read_fav(_key[index])!=null && read_fav(_key[index]) == true
                                    ? Colors.blue
                                    : Colors.black,
                              )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the code like,

```
    Future<bool> _isfav(String post_key) async {
    bool _is_fav;
    var snapData = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child(Common.user)
        .child(Common.number)
        .child("favourite")
        .child(post_key)
        .once();

    if (v.value != null) {
      _is_fav = true;
    } else {
      _is_fav = false;
    }

    return _is_fav;
  }

  Future<bool> read_fav(String index) async{
    bool data=false;
    data=await _isfav(index);
    return data;
  }
```

Also, read_fav will be a future method. because it depends on _isFav() return value which will be predicted in future.

```
bool isReadFav=await read_fav(index);
```

Just refer dart await and then concepts at [Here](https://toastguyz.com/dart/dart-async/)

You're all set.

Comment: actually i am checking here

Comment: child: Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                    color:read_fav(_key[index])!=null && read_fav(_key[index]) == true
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.black,
                                  )),